How to get rid of build error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" (at hasSyntacticModifier)?
We have Vue 3 app (the migration from Vue 2 to Vue 3 is in progress) with Vite and TypeScript. There are a lot of .js files. When I run: npm run dev, the app is normally running. When I try to build it using: npm run build:
"build": "run-p type-check \"build-only {@}\" --"

I get the following error:
transforming (1134) node_modules\@xmldom\xmldom\lib\dom-parser.jsD:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\vue-tsc\index.js:34
            throw err;
            ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at hasSyntacticModifier (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:16592:30)
    at getFunctionFlags (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:15489:11)
    at getSingleReturnExpression (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:86165:11)
    at getPossibleTypeNodeReuseExpression (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:86160:73)
    at serializeReturnTypeForSignatureWorker (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:51756:45)
    at serializeReturnTypeForSignature (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:51734:26)
    at signatureToSignatureDeclarationHelper (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:50828:30)
    at createTypeNodeFromObjectType (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:50317:35)
    at visitAndTransformType (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:50262:24)
    at createAnonymousTypeNode (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:50202:20)

Node.js v22.11.0
ERROR: "type-check" exited with 1.

or
transforming (1263) node_modules\lodash\_freeGlobal.jsD:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\vue-tsc\index.js:34
            throw err;
            ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at hasSyntacticModifier (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:16592:30)
    at getFunctionFlags (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:15489:11)
    at getSingleReturnExpression (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:86165:11)
    at getPossibleTypeNodeReuseExpression (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:86160:73)
    at serializeReturnTypeForSignatureWorker (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:51756:45)
    at serializeReturnTypeForSignature (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:51734:26)
    at signatureToSignatureDeclarationHelper (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:50828:30)
    at createTypeNodeFromObjectType (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:50317:35)
    at visitAndTransformType (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:50262:24)
    at createAnonymousTypeNode (D:\projects\portal-internal\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:50202:20)

Node.js v22.11.0
ERROR: "type-check" exited with 1.

Without type-check switch:
"build": "run-p \"build-only {@}\" --"

Everything works fine.
How to get rid of the error?
